# Scala variable type mismatch?

Tags: scala, variables, type-mismatch

```
class New {

  val x : Option[String] = "abc"
  val y : String = "abc"

  if(x == y) "YES" else "No"

}

  **Error:(5, 28) type mismatch;
  found   : String("abc")
  required: Option[String]
  val x : Option[String] = "abc"**
```

I am facing above type mismatch error. Can someone help to resolve above error?

Comment: Considering that you are facing such issues, I will advise you to learn Scala in a more structured manner. I suggest reading the book Essential Scala. You can download this for free on - https://underscore.io/training/courses/essential-scala/

Comment: your problem is you trying assign `String` value to `x` but declare `x` as `Option[String]` this is different types. try to wrap `"abc"`: `Option("abc")` and after that you will need to wrap `y` also for comparing. Read more about option for using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The type mismatch is because `String` and `Option[String]` are different types and you can't directly compare them.

You probably want this:

```
if (x.contains(y)) "YES" else "No"
```

This checks whether `x` has something in it (is not `None`) and, if so, whether that something equals `y`.